# Do we need a makebst tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are [around 60 questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=makebst+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bcustom-bib%5D+-%5Bbiblatex%5D) that contain `makebst`, but no corresponding tag. Should we create one?

Comment: There are around  6,614 questions containing `cannot`, but no corresponding tag. Should we create one? There are around 967 containing `AMS` (or `ams`), around 741 containing `obsolete` and around 1,373 containing `weird`. That is, why this in particular? I'm not sure total number of questions is a good guide to whether a tag is likely to be a useful one or not. (I'm not saying it wouldn't be: just that I don't think the numbers can make the case on their own.)

Comment: We already have a `custom-bib` tag, so really all that is needed is to make `makebst` a synonym, and perhaps add the `custom-bib` tag to some of the questions that are missing it. Oddly I don't have enough reputation in the tag to even *suggest* a synonym (SE works in mysterious ways...) but certainly a moderator could do that.

Comment: @cfr This is a bit ... populist. `makebst` is a clearly separate program, and hardly someone uses `makebst` and not mean this program. That's not the case with `cannot` (which is a standard English word) nor with `ams` (who maintain lots and lots of separate stuff).

Comment: @yo' Indeed. My point was that the question doesn't make a case either way because the reason given for considering the tag is not a good one. Numbers are part of the picture (no point in a tag for 1 question unless you think others will then use it, at least) but they can't make the case for a tag on their own. That was my only point. I hoped somebody would expand the question to say why *this* tag might be considered a useful addition.

Comment: @cfr: I asked a question about `makebst` and have not found the [tag:custom-bib] tag; I would have found it if there was an alias. The figure I gave is just an indicator that there seems to be some interest in this tool. [None of these questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=makebst+is%3Aquestion+%5Btag%3Acustom-bib%5D) seem to be tagged as "custom-bib", although that tag would be appropriate for quite a few of them.

Comment: So probably @AlanMunn 's suggestion is a good one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Making this an answer, since it seems to have enough support.)

We already have a [custom-bib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-bib) tag, so really all that is needed is to make [makebst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/makebst) a synonym, and perhaps add the [custom-bib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-bib) tag to some of the questions that are missing it. Oddly I don't have enough reputation in the tag to even suggest a synonym (SE works in mysterious ways...) but certainly a moderator could do that.

Just be aware before going on a tagging spree, that adding a tag to a question bumps it to the front page, so it's best to do tagging in small sets over a few days if there are many questions in need of new tags.

Comment: There don't seem to be many users who are able to create the synonym now, it must be a user with "[a total answer score of 5 or more on that tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/208735)": http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcustom-bib%5D+is%3Aanswer. Perhaps a moderator can do this?

Comment: @krlmlr Done :-)